# Every page reflecting date from the one page issue

Tags: sql, powerbi, reporting, business-intelligence

I am new to Power BI. There are date columns in al tables in my power BI. I am not sure what I did but as per its default settings, on any number of pages within a single Power BI file. The date function was independent, but now if in one page I use date from table A the same will be reflected in all the pages. Could you please let me know how to revert it back so that the date function field is independent across the pages?

Answer (score 0):

Go to the relationship view and delete all those relations on the date columns that you don‘t need.